# Knex.js + mysql2: Get number of inserted and updated rows

Tags: javascript, knex.js, node-mysql2

I'm using Knex.js and mysql2. Is there a way to figure out how many rows were inserted and how many were updated in this function?

```
await this.knex("tableName")
    .insert(arrayOfObjects)
    .onConflict(["primaryKey1", "primaryKey2"])
    .merge()
```